# Found bounds for a sum of binom coefficients(generalization of Vandermonde's identity)

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to find some upper and lower bounds for the following expression:
$$\sum_{v=0}^t  {{x-v}\choose{y}} \cdot {x\choose{v}}\cdot {z-x \choose  {t-v}}$$
Given that $x-t>y>0,z>x+t,t\geq 1$.

Finding the exact expression can be done only by hypergeometric function, which is not easy to compute:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=approx+sum_%28v%3D1%29%5Et++%28%28%28x-v%29+choose+y%29*%28x+choose+v%29*%28%28z-x%29+choose+t-v

Using Vandermonde's identity, an upper bound is $${x\choose{y}}\cdot {z \choose  {t}}$$  and a lower bound is

$${x-t\choose{y}}\cdot {z \choose  {t}}$$

My question is there any better upper\lower bounds, that are more tight?

Comment: This seems too vague to have a real answer. Maybe if you had some particular regime you were interested in? Very likely one term dominates the sum, perhaps the first or last. You can then for instance use Stirling's approximation (maybe in logarithmic form), which is a mess but quite good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists a closed-form exact solution for the following summation $S$ proposed in the OP:

$$\sum_{v=0}^t  \binom{x-v} y \binom xv \binom{z-x}{t-v}$$

As shown below, this is given by

$$S=\binom xy \binom {z-y}{t} $$

---

To prove this solution, we can start by writing the binomials using factorials. Collecting the fixed factors (i.e. the terms not containing $v$) out the summation and simplifying we have

$$S= \frac{x!(z-x)!}{ y!} \sum_{v=1}^t   \frac{1}{(t-v)!\,(x-y-v)!\,\, (z-x-t+v)!v!}\\$$

Rewriting the factors of the denominator in a different way, we have
$$S=  \frac{x!(z-x)!}{ y!}   \sum _{v=1}^{t} \frac {(-t)_{v}}{t!} \,\frac{[-(x-y)]_{v}}{(x-y)!}\, \frac{1}{(z-x-t+1)_{v}(z-x-t)!}\, \frac{1}{v!}$$

where $(k)_v$ indicates the Pochhammer symbol for rising factorial. Collecting the new fixed terms in the summation and noting that $(-t)_v/v!=(-1)^v \binom tv$, we have

$$S=\frac{x!(z-x)!}{t!\,y!\,(x-y)!(z-x-t)!}  \\ \sum _{v=0}^{t} (-1)^v \binom tv  \,\frac{(y-x)_{v}} {(z-x-t+1)_{v}}\\
=\binom xy \binom {z-x}{t}\\ \sum _{v=0}^{t} (-1)^v \binom tv  \,\frac{(y-x)_{v}} {(z-x-t+1)_{v}}$$

The sum can be expressed by a hypergeometric function, reminding that this function is defined by the power series

$${\displaystyle {}_{2}F_{1}(a,b,c;d)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {(a)_{n}(b)_{n}}{(c)_{n}}}{\frac {d^{n}}{n!}}}$$

and that when either $a$ or $b$ is a nonpositive integer it reduces to the finite sum

$$\displaystyle {}_{2}F_{1}(-a,b,c;z)=\sum _{n=0}^{a}(-1)^{n}{\binom {a}{n}}{\frac {(b)_{n}}{(c)_{n}}}z^{n}$$

So, setting $a=t$, $b=y-x$, $c=z-x-t+1$, $d=1$, and $n=v$, we get

$$S=\binom xy \binom {z-x}{t} \\ 2F_1(-t,y-x,z-x-t+1;1)$$

which is equivalent to the expression given by WA in the link of the OP, with the only difference that here the sum starts from $v=0$.

Now we can use the well known  identity

$$\displaystyle {}_{2}F_{1}(a,b;c;1)={\frac {\Gamma (c)\Gamma (c-a-b)}{\Gamma (c-a)\Gamma (c-b)}}$$

to get

$$S=\binom xy \binom {z-x}{t}  \\
 {\frac {\Gamma (z-x-t+1)\Gamma (z-y+1)}{\Gamma (z-x+1)\Gamma (z-y-t+1)}} $$

and then

$$S=\binom xy \binom {z-x}{t} 
 {\frac { (z-x-t)! (z-y)!}{ (z-x)!(z-y-t)!}} \\
 =\binom xy \binom {z-y}{t}  $$

---

As an example, let us set $x=6$, $y=2$, $z=10$, and $t=3$. The original summation gives

$$\sum_{v=0}^3  \binom{6-v} 2 \binom 6v \binom{4}{3-v}=840$$

as shown by WA [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bv%3D0%7D%5E3++binom%286-v%2C+2%29+*+binom%286%2Cv%29+*+binom%284%2C3-v%29%3D). Accordingly

$$\binom 62 \binom 83 =15\cdot 56=840$$

As another example with larger numbers, let us set $x=15$, $y=5$, $z=24$, and $t=8$. The original summation gives

$$\sum_{v=0}^8  \binom{15-v} 5 \binom {15}v \binom{9}{8-v}=226972746$$

as shown by WA [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bv%3D0%7D%5E8+binom%2815-v%2C+5%29+*+binom%2815%2Cv%29+*+binom%289%2C8-v%29).  Accordingly

$$\binom {15}5 \binom {19}{8} =3003\cdot 75582=226972746$$

Comment: Well, it is almost the solution, since we sum from $v=0$ and not $v=1$.
But you will get the bounty :)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I assumed that the sum was from $v=1$ because this was the lower bound of the summation used in the WA link that you posted. I will edit my answer for the summation starting from $v=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the summand is
$$ {\frac {x!\, \left( z-v \right) !}{y!\, \left( x-v-y \right) !\,v!\,
 \left( t-v \right) !\, \left( z-t \right) !}}
$$
where $(z-t)! \le (z-v)! \le (z-1)!$, $(x-t-y)! \le (x-v-y)! \le (x-1-y)!$,
and $ (\lfloor t/2 \rfloor)! (\lceil t/2 \rceil)! \le v! (t-v)! \le t! $
so
$$ \frac{x!}{y! (x-1-y)! t!} \le  {\frac {x!\, \left( z-v \right) !}{y!\, \left( x-v-y \right) !\,v!\,
 \left( t-v \right) !\, \left( z-t \right) !}} \le \frac{x! (z-1)!}{y! (x-t-y)! (\lfloor t/2 \rfloor)! (\lceil t/2 \rceil)! (z-t)!}$$
Multiply left and right sides by $t$ to get lower and upper bounds.

Comment: The bounds are not tight, i.e., with Vandermonde's identity we can get better bounds

Comment: The right-most factor in the summand is $\binom{z-x}{t-v}$, not $\binom{z-v}{t-v}$ as you seem to have assumed.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my question independently to the algebraic solution presented here using combinatorics. I will prove that
$$\sum_{v=0}^t  {{x-v}\choose{y}} \cdot {x\choose{v}}\cdot {z-x \choose  {t-v}}={{x}\choose{y}}\cdot {z-y \choose  {t}}  $$

We have $z$ balls, numbered from $1$ to $z$. Among them, $x$ of them are green and  $z-x$ are red.

Lets count the number of options to select $y$ green balls, and then select $t$ balls (which can be either red or green) from the remaining $z-y$ balls. Selecting the $y$ green balls is called the **first stage**, and selecting the $t$ balls is the **second stage**.

The number of options in the first stage is ${{x}\choose{y}}$, and the number of options of the second stage is ${z-y \choose  {t}}$. Thus, the number of options is $${{x}\choose{y}}\cdot {z-y \choose  {t}}.$$

Alternatively, we can count the number of options, given that we have selected $v$ green balls in the second stage (i.e., where $0\leq v\leq t$). There are ${{x}\choose{v}}$ ways to choose these green balls. We then select ${{x-v}\choose{y}}$ green balls for the first stage, and  ${{z-x}\choose{t-v}}$ for the red balls of the second stage. Thus the number of options is $$\sum_{v=0}^t  {{x-v}\choose{y}} \cdot {x\choose{v}}\cdot {z-x \choose  {t-v}},$$

and that proves that both equations are equal.